# Linux bash // Date: Working with variables and date

Tags: linux, bash, date, variables

I am wondering about a certain problem:
I want to "increment" a date using a mathematical expression, using two variables.

A bash script has a variable (date):

`TS=$(date +%y-%m-%d)`

I want to process that within a loop:

```
for((i=1; i<=$iquant; i++))
do
FTS=`date '+%y-%m-%d' -d "$TS+'$i*$iquant' days"`
FFTS=`date '+%y-%m-%d' -d "$FTS+'$idays' days"`
echo $FTS
echo $FFTS
done
```

When running Console shows:

```
date: invalid date ‘16-11-06+'1*5' days’
date: invalid date ‘+'5' days’
```

It seems that the variables are no calculated...using back ticks should prevent this? Does anyone have a suggestion or maybe a better way to solve this? regards Josi

SYSTEM: 4.4.0-21-generic LINUX UBUNTU

Comment: my date manpage does not describe anything about "calculating", does yours? `man date`

Comment: yes, confirmed. Mine also doesnt say anything about calculating ;). I think this should be the job of bash and then hand it to date?

Answer (score 2):

In bash, text concatenation is default. To compute something explicitly, use expressions with dollar+double parentheses, like this: `$(($i*$iquant))` ([arithmetic expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith)) or more simply, since we're now in a "math" context: `$((i*iquant))` (no need for dollar prefix)

And drop the single quotes, which are misleading for the parsing of the `date` command.

Fixed code (using `iquant=5`, ran today):

```
TS=$(date +%y-%m-%d)

for((i=1; i<=iquant; i++))
do
  FTS=`date '+%y-%m-%d' -d "$TS + $((i*iquant)) days"`
  FFTS=`date '+%y-%m-%d' -d "$FTS + $idays days"`
  echo "$FTS"
  echo "$FFTS"
done
```

result:

```
16-11-11
16-11-12
16-11-16
16-11-17
16-11-21
16-11-22
16-11-26
16-11-27
16-12-01
16-12-02
```

Comment: Note that `$[]` parentheses also provide arithmetic context, just like `$(())`.

Comment: @hidefromkgb `$[]` works, but it's undocumented, non-POSIX and deprecated, see [this post by the Bash maintainer](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00034.html).

Comment: This might be an old question, but @Josi Dunk, if you feel like this answers your questions, please do go ahead and mark it as an accepted answer, this helps SO and everyone else looking for an answer to something similar.